# Rcpp multiply vectors extracted from rows of matrix to form a matrix

Tags: r, rcpp

In Rcpp, I am attempting to extract each row of a *n* by *q* matrix *B* to give vector *b*.  I then want to multiply these vectors as *t(b)*b* to output a *q* by *q* matrix.  However, when i do this, i get the following error message:

"conversion from 'Rcpp::sugar::Times_Vector_Vector<14, true, Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorgar>, true, Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >' to non-scalar type 'Rcpp:NumericMatrix {aka Rcpp::Matrix<14>}' requested"

I'm very new to Rcpp and so not sure where to start to sort this out.  Any advice as to what I've done wrong would be gratefully received.

Current code (where `iter` is a counter that counts through rows of the matrix):

```
NumericVector b_1 = B(iter,_);
b_1.attr("dim") = Dimension(1, ql);
NumericMatrix b_2 = as<NumericMatrix>(b_1);
NumericMatrix b_3= transpose(b_2) * b_2;
```

Comment: You're better off using `RcppArmadillo` if you're doing matrix algebra.

Comment: Apologies-  caught enter before I'd finished typing.  Error message now included.  Would it be possible to have an example of how to do this in RcppArmadillo?

Comment: You may want to check out the [`RcppArmadillo` introduction vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo/vignettes/RcppArmadillo-intro.pdf), which has an example of essentially exactly what you want to do I think (on page 5)

Comment: Search for `[rcpp] rcpparmadillo` here at StackOverflow, study the 700+ packages on CRAN using RcppArmadillo, or maybe even consider the RcppArmadillo or Armadillo documentation.  Kidding aside, Armadillo docs are _excellent_ and we tried to help on our side too.

Comment: Thanks - using the example on page 5 has solved the issue